# Spring Data JPA: How to query a list of dates?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I need a Spring Data JPA (Postgresql) query that searches for a `List` of `java.util.Date` values. My first attempt at the query was this:

```
List<PricingCoreViewEntity> findByProductIdAndEffectiveDateIn(
            String productId, @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) List<Date> effectiveDates, Sort orderBy);
```

But that doesn't work because `List` is not temporal, it's the dates within the `List` that are. So how else can I write this? TIA.

Comment: Why do you need to add the annotation?

Comment: I just assumed I did. We always query with the annotation. Is it not needed?

Comment: Yes, it should work without it.

Comment: @IslamMuhammad You are right, it does work!! You should make an answer so I can accept & upvote. Thanks!

Comment: You are more than welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the annotation, it's not needed.